# __has_feature(objc_arc) does not work for c++ static library linked to iOS app

Tags: ios, macros, automatic-ref-counting, static-libraries, llvm

So I have a simple iOS project which has to use static library. The library is written mainly in c++ and tends to be cross platform. It can be built using Xcode.

I create a sample iOS app project, add the library's project to it as a subproject, add library as a dependancy for my iOS app.

My iOS app uses ARC. In the library I have several preprocessor macros like

```
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
  @autoreleasepool
#elif defined(OSX) || defined(IOS)
  // something else ...
```

When I compile project it is compiled **with ARC not enabled**. So "// something else ..." is set in code instead of "@autoreleasepool".

I even set additional -fobjc_arc flags to library target and to specific file where these macros are used. Please see the screenshot.

I use Xcode Version 4.6.2 (4H1003), compiler is Apple LLVM 4.2.

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *expect* that it happens because clang will ignore that option when compiling C++.  You need to avoid C++ seeing that declaration at all (`@autoreleasepool` is illegal in C++ anyway) using a guard:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
  @autoreleasepool
#elif defined(OSX) || defined(IOS)
  // something else ...
#endif
#endif // __OBJC__
```

in those header files that are shared between C++ and Objective-C++.

It's not immediately obvious to me why plain C++ would be interested in seeing this header anyway, given it is incapable of using Objective-C objects (only Objective-C++ can). Perhaps you can expand on that in order to solve this issue properly?

Comment: Yes. You are correct. I didn't think that clang ignores such options when compiling C++. After changing file extension from .cc to .mm problem went away.
Regarding headers visibility: you are correct again. Now it brings another question regarding C++ library, it seems that it is intended to be Objective-C++ for iOS.

Comment: @user1264176 If you want this library to remain cross-platform then renaming source files to `.mm` will cause an issue.  If you want a *callback mechanism*, which is the only *C++ calls Objective-C/C++* use case I have personally used, then a simple C-like callback mechanism is possible, which allows the library to be used from both C++ and Objective-C++.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. I wrote regarding file renaming just to confirm your answer. It seems that I will need rethink my approach to this app and library.
Thank you for help.